# Selecting (Relatively) Large Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google CloudSQL and have the following simple code:

```
<?php
$db = new pdo ( 'mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<appid:id>;dbname=<database_name>', 'root', '' );
$db->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$stmt = $db->prepare ( "SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 FROM table" );
$stmt->execute ();
$returned = $stmt->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
echo json_encode ( $returned );
?>
```

But because the database table is too large (close to 150,000 lines), it seems like it's not being handled correctly. I keep getting this error message:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

I know that the problem is size because as soon as I `SELECT` only 3 columns instead of 5, it displays it just fine. In my opinion, 150,000 lines is not asking for too much; but it is the largest table I've created, so I don't know what I'm missing.

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

I've also tried to upgrade the tier from D0 (125 MB) to D1 (512 MB), but that hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 1):

This warning occurs when you have exceeded your Memory Limit for your App Engine Instance Class. I am assuming you are in the Instance Class ‘B1’ since 150000 rows of data is exceeding that. You can change your Instance Class by setting its value in your app.yaml file. I would recommend going through [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/#PHP_Instance_scaling_and_class) to choose an Instance Class that fits your needs, anything above B1 and F1 should provide you with enough memory. Also make sure you are closing your connection by setting `$db = null;`